# Automaticly inserting text into dxf file with python

Tags: python, text, insert, dxf

I‘m trying to automatically insert text into dxf contours using python. I have a bulk of dxf files for lasercutting. Often we want to engrave the partnumber into the sheetmetal part.
My attempt is to make a square box Where the length and with equals the text height and width. After to Programm found a place where it is outside the innerconturs and inside the outer contour I want to fill the box with text. I tried to abstract the contours with a polygon and start checking if it fits or not, which kind of works ok. Not finish completely yet.

I wondered if there is some sort of library /tool that has this function because computing time is quite high atm before putting more afford into the Programm or anyone has an easier approach than mine.

Answer (score 0):

The next release of [ezdxf](https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/index.html) ([v0.16](https://pypi.org/project/ezdxf/0.16b0/) is in beta now), has a new [text2path](https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/addons/text2path.html) add-on, which uses Matplotlib to render text strings as path objects. This path objects can be placed as:

- POLYLINE and SPLINE entities to preserves the smooth curves
- flattened to POLYLINE or LWPOLYLINE entities, which consist only of straight lines
- HATCH entities with or without spline edges
- flatten the paths into simple vertices

There are some examples in the https://github.com/mozman/ezdxf/tree/master/examples/addons folder (*_to_path.py).

It is possible to transform the path objects by a `Matrix44` transformation and there even exist a function to fit some paths into a box: [fit_paths_into_box()](https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/path.html#ezdxf.path.fit_paths_into_box).

For additional questions, you can use the [discussions](https://github.com/mozman/ezdxf/discussions) board at github.